# Which classes of method argument may be annotated with @RequestHeader

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

I want to access the time-stamp in a `If-Modified-Since` header, so I can implement conditional GET.

Spring controllers can use the [`@RequestHeader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) annotation to indicate that Spring should pass the value of an HTTP header to a handler method as a method argument. Must the argument be a `String`? Or are other classes permitted? The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html) implies that `long` values can be converted. But what is the set of classes permitted?

Will the following work (using a `Date`)?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"If-Modified-Since" })
public final void conditionallyRetrieve(
   @RequestHeader("If-Modified-Since")final Date ifModifiedSince,
   final HttpServletResponse response) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically, in your example, I think you can use [`DateTimeFormat`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) to drive Spring to do the conversion:

```
@RequestHeader("If-Modified-Since") 
  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "ThePATTERN") final Date ifModifiedSince
```

Comment: Can `@DateTimeFormat` can be applied to `@Controller` method arguments? This example shows they can, although it is not a `@RequestHeader` argument: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch15s03.html

Comment: If you're using Spring 3.1+, read [this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10105?focusedCommentId=86207&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-86207); it should be OK.

Comment: Good find; the issue suggests using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'")`.

Comment: However, the HTTP specification says that, although that format is the preferred format, servers must accept the two other, deprecated, formats. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.3.1